# using gulp-proxy-connect for AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, grunt-connect-proxy, gulp-connect

I started using gulp for my project. Earlier in the project i used grunt in which i was able to configure Ajax requests using grunt-connect-proxy.

GruntFile.js

```
connect: {

            options: {
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: 9001,
                open: true,
                base: ['../'],
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        proxySnippet,
                        connect.static('../')

                    ];
                },
                livereload: true
            },

        proxies: [
            {
                context: '/data/fetch',
                host: 'prt-service.test.com',
                port: 8080,
                https: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            },
            {
                context: '/data/report',
                host: 'prt-service.test.com',
                port: 8080,
                https: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            },
            {
                context: '/data/group',
                host: 'prt-service.test.com',
                port: 8080,
                https: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        ],

    },
```

I tried to do the same using gulp-connect-proxy but not able to acheive the same

GulpFile.js

```
connect.server({
  root: "../",
  port: 3000,
  livereload: true,
      middleware: function (connect, opt) {
      opt.route = 'prt-service.test.com/data/';
      var proxy = new Proxy(opt);
      return [proxy];
  }
});
```

what i am doing wrong here. could you please provide me a soltuion

Comment: I think you have missed to define `connect.server({ ... });` inside gulp task
`gulp.task('connect', function () { // connect });`

[check this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-proxy)

Comment: @Vinodhan no. i did defined the task but it works using 'http-proxy-middleware' :)  var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/data', {target: 'prt-service.test.com'}); browserSync.init({

  server:{
   baseDir: "../",
   port: 3000,
         middleware: [proxy]
  }

 });